# how to declare the variable with the value which contains special characters in web.config

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-config

I am reading the some URL value from web.config file using javascript. But dont know how to declare the variable with the value which contains special characters. The URL is like below:

```
http://roolpio.com/PDF/CustomPages/Ut/Reader.asp?SID=" + SessionId + "&Key0=4&Key4=1&J=Ut/Reader.asp&T=User
```

How to declare these type of variables with values which contains special characters ?

Answer (score 0):

The `web.config` is an XML file, so you need to escape XML characters using XML escapes.

That means, `&` becomes `&amp;`.

See [What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters) :

```
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
```